# Remove characters before ( in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I wanted to remove any character before ( in snowflake.
For example: If the data has "Hello(World)", I want only "(World)".

Comment: Use a combination of the POSITION and RIGHT functions

Comment: I see a 'best' answer has been accepted but the answers all have different behaviour depending on whether the varchar (a) doesn't contain an open brace '(' and/or (b) contains a subsequent '('. Ideally a question like this should specify the required behaviour including special and degenerate cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SUBSTR` and `CHARINDEX` functions:

```
CREATE TABLE tab AS SELECT 'Hello(World)' AS col;

SELECT SUBSTR(col, CHARINDEX('(', col))
FROM tab;
-- (World)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regexp_substr function to extract text and use a greedy expression:

```
set str = 'Hello (world)';

select regexp_substr($str, '\\((.+)\\)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of `SPLIT` and `SPLIT_PART`

```
CREATE TABLE tab AS SELECT 'Hello(World)' AS col;

SELECT '(' || SPLIT_PART(col, '(', 2)
FROM tab;
-- (World)
```